# Find cell next to cell where value is placed

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, cell

I insert the value of TextBox1 (on a UserForm) into the first empty cell at the bottom of Column A on Sheet("Info").

I am trying to modify this code so that the value in TextBox2 goes into cell in Column B next to the cell where TextBox1 was added.

I cannot use the same formula, because all the cells in Column A will have values, while corresponding cells in Column B may be blank.

```vb
Public Function FindNextEmpty(ByVal rCell As Range) As Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

With rCell
   If Len(.Formula) = 0 Then
      Set FindNextEmpty = rCell
   ElseIf Len(.Offset(1, 0).Formula) = 0 Then
      Set FindNextEmpty = .Offset(1, 0)
   Else
      Set FindNextEmpty = .End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
   End If
End With

Exit Function
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description & ", Function FindNextEmpty."
End Function


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim rCell As Range

Set rCell = FindNextEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Range("A1"))

rCell.Value = TextBox1.Value

Set rCell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
rCell.Offset(0, 1) = TextBox2.Value
```

after

```
rCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
```

got me where I needed to be.